# Extract string literal type of an interface's function's arguments

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, backend, phantomjs

In [@types/phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/phantom), there is a WebPage interface, which includes the following function:

```
interface WebPage {
    // ...
    property(
        key:
            | "content"
            | "plainText"
            | "focusedFrameName"
            | "frameContent"
            | "frameName"
            | "framePlainText"
            | "frameTitle"
            | "libraryPath"
            | "offlineStoragePath"
            | "title"
            | "url"
            | "windowName",
    ): Promise<string>;
}
```

I'm trying to extract the property of "key" and use it in a generic.

I'm expecting the following:

```
async getPageProperty<T extends Parameters<WebPage["property"]>[0]>(url: string, property: T){
   // ...
}
```

to interpret the the "key" argument's type as `"content" | "plainText" | "focusedFrameName" | ...` , but, to my surprise, I get:

`(type parameter) T in PhantomJS.getPageProperty<T extends string>(url: string, property: T): Promise<T>` .

Is there any way to correctly type T as the string literal instead of just "string" ?

Comment: Not related to your question, but it's worth noting that `phantom` was deprecated 5 years ago.

Comment: @EricHaynes I'm aware, I was using it since I noticed that its performance seemed better in comparison with alternatives like Selenium or Puppeteer (at least in my test cases) for web scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is correct if that were the only signature of the function. The problem is that the types for phantom have multiple overloads for `property`, not just the one that you provide. Thus, the extracted type is the union of all of those possible types of `key`, and some of them have `key` as simply `string`.

```js
    property(key: "framesName" | "pagesWindowName" | "pages"): Promise<string[]>;
    property(key: "canGoBack" | "canGoForward" | "navigationLocked" | "ownsPages"): Promise<boolean>;
    property(key: "framesCount" | "offlineStorageQuota" | "zoomFactor"): Promise<number>;
    property(key: "clipRect"): Promise<{
        top: number;
        left: number;
        width: number;
        height: number;
    }>;
    property(key: "cookies"): Promise<ICookie[]>;
    property(key: "customHeaders"): Promise<{ [key: string]: string }>;
    property(key: "paperSize"): Promise<IPaperSizeOptions>;
    property(key: "scrollPosition"): Promise<{ top: number; left: number }>;
    property(key: "viewportSize"): Promise<{ width: number; height: number }>;
    property<T>(key: string): Promise<T>;
    property<T>(key: string, value: T): Promise<void>;
```

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ced533042db1b1663be0397fca6e2382dbcbf263/types/phantom/index.d.ts#L196-L226